# Editing a layer using pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am loading a network layer in qgis 3.32 using my custom plugin.
I am turning on the editing session on the layer using startEditing.

```
 def open_editing_toolbar(self):
        self.layers_to_edit = [
            self.node_layer,
            self.network_layer,
            self.taz_layer
            ]
        for layer in self.layers_to_edit:
            if layer:
                if not layer.isEditable():
                    layer.startEditing()
 if self.node_layer:
            self.node_layer.featureAdded.connect(self.onNodeFeatureAdded)
if self.network_layer:
            self.network_layer.featureAdded.connect(self.onNetworkFeatureAdded)
```

Then I am adding a link using qgis toolbar, the feature form opens up, I add the values, press ok. Then the signal goes to the function connected where i do further processin.
Then I have another button in my plugin to turn off the editing session on the layers.

```
def validate_save_changes(self):
        if self.node_layer:
            self.node_layer.featureAdded.disconnect(self.onNodeFeatureAdded)
        if self.network_layer:
            self.network_layer.featureAdded.disconnect(self.onNetworkFeatureAdded)
        if self.taz_layer:
            self.taz_layer.featureAdded.disconnect(self.onTazFeatureAdded)
            
        for layer in self.layers_to_edit:
           if layer and layer.isEditable():
                try:   
                    layer.commitChanges() 
                    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

**Once the changes are saved, I am facing few errors as below:**
1- The added link disappears. When I zoom out manually on qgis, then the newly added link appears again, but on zooming in it disappear.
2- When I use 'identify features' from qgis toolbar, I press on the link - even though the link exists , it says no features found.
**Note** - The newly added link attributes are present in the attribute table.

Can someone tell me what the issue is. Is it happening because of triggerRepaint() or any other thing which I am missing in the "validate_save_changes" function.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what links are, where and how they disappear, where you click them, and how QGIS gives you an error. It is desirable to describe your problem in more detail, maybe attach screenshots for ease of understanding.

Comment: In my opinion, the above code can be simplified, but there is nothing in it that could cause incorrect behavior in the Qgis interface.